how do you give cloudfront access to s3 that has been encrypted by aws managed KMS?
Currently I am trying to deploy cloudfront backed by s3.  Contents in s3 are encrypted with the aws managed kms.  This is causing the and 403 error since I am not able to give CF access to the key.  When I follow the instruction below and create my own key and update the s3 encrypt key, I am able to fetch the file.  Is there anyway to bypass it and give the permission on the aws managed key?
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serving-sse-kms-encrypted-content-from-s3-using-cloudfront/
